# Custom Spring HATEOAS response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hateoas

I have a Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<StudentResource>> getList(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) String sort,
            @RequestParam(value = "sort.dir", required = false) String sortOrder,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String username

            //@RequestParam(required=false) Map<String, String> searchParams
            ) {

        Map<String, String> searchParams = new HashMap<>();
        if(username != null) searchParams.put("username", username);
        if(name != null) searchParams.put("name", name);

        PageSearchModel model = new PageSearchModel(page, sort, sortOrder, searchParams);

        List<Student> students = studentService.getList(model);

        if (students == null)
            return null;

        List<StudentResource> resources = students.stream()
                .map(student -> studentResourceAssembler.toResource(student))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(StudentController.class)
                .getList(null,null,null,null,null))
                .withSelfRel();

        return new ResponseEntity(new Resources<StudentResource>(resources, selfLink), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The parameters are used for pagination and search, what I want is to generate a self link with all the parameters even if they are option, but what I'm getting is:

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students{?page,sort,sort.dir,name,username}"
    }
```

}

Also is there a way to include the HttpMethod on the link?

**EDIT:** Also for POST methods, for example, to insert a new Student, is there a way to include in the link the structure for the Model?

Comment: What is `methodOn` method?

Comment: Returns a ControllerLinkBuilder, and is supposed to get the URI for the method of that Controller. Maybe I'm using it the wrong way

Comment: _"what I want is to generate a self link with all the parameters even if they are option, but what I'm getting is"_ What you get is exactly what you describe, so I'm confused. If you want the parameter _values_ to show up in the link you need to pass them to `getList`.